# KnockoutJs & Asp.Net MVC 4 - Changing View Model depend on selected type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I'm working with MVC 4 and KnockoutJs and I get a stuck with this scenario

I have an object (called parent) which have a property named ChildType

**_ If ChildType = 1 ---> I will render Partial-A with ViewModel-A

_ If ChildType = 2 ---> I will render Partial-B with ViewModel-B**

I found not much article or answer for my issue. Most of all, they suggest a master ViewModel, somehow it's the best way, but if we have more than 2 child-viewmodel, it means that the master viewmodel is so large.

So, please help me to implement it.

Regards..

Answer (score 0):

Use the template binding

```
<!-- ko template: { name: childTemplate, data: childModel } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

childTemplate is a observable, either a computed or a standard observable that will return a string with the name of the template to render. childModel a observable or computed that will return the selected childModel

Also if childModel can be null then you need to add a if check to the template binding otherwise you will get a null error

```
<!-- ko template: { name: childTemplate, data: childModel, if: childModel } -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the template binding:

```
 <!-- ko template: { name: templateName, data: modelName, if: modelName } -->
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Then, in your view model add the following observable:
templateName and modelName.

Your view model will probably look like this:

```
var parent = {
    ChildType: ko.observable(1),
    templateName: ko.observable('Partial-A'),
    modelName: ko.observable(ViewModelA)
};
```

The next thing to do is to set the templateName and modelName according to ChildType values.

```
var option = parent.ChildType();

if(option == 1)
{
      parent.modelName(null);
      parent.templateName('Partial-A');
      parent.modelName(ViewModelA);
 }
```

It is very important to set the modelName to null before changing the template name, because ko will not be able to apply bindings.

Next you just define your template, like this:

```
<script id="Partial-A" type="text/html">  
 // your code goes here
</script>
```